# Merge sed commands into a script

Tags: linux, sed

I need to write these two sed commands in a single script.

```
sed -n '10,20p' file.txt | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
```

I selects lines in range from 10 to 20 and prints them in a reverse order
Could anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Help you with what? That line can be used in a script?

Comment: I need to make a .sed file that I can run using "sed -f script.sed file.txt"

Comment: Commands in a script file all operate on the original input, it can't be used easily to pipe the output of one command to another. So you need to change the address specification in the second command so it refers to the addresses in the original file. `1!` should become `10!`.

Comment: That doesn't work because the first command has a parameter -n and the second does not. I would have to run it like "sed -n -f scipt.sed file.txt" but this would apply the parameter to both commands

Comment: I don't think you need the first command. Delete lines 1-9, leave line 10 in the pattern space, then run the second command on lines 11-20.

Comment: Perhaps `sed -n '10,20p' file.txt | tac` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working

```
#!/bin/sed -Ef

10!G
h
20!d
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If `sed` is still your most preferable tool then:

```
$ seq 20 | sed -n '10,15{10!G;h;15p}'
15
14
13
12
11
10
```

However, I don't like that line numbers (10 & 15) needs to be specified twice. `sed -n '10,20p' file.txt | tac` seems better...